# Utilisation du "lorsque" en logique

Tags: sens, usage, conjonctions, mathématiques, coordination

Je travaille présentement sur un travail de logique où l'on nous demande de traduire l'énoncé suivant en expression logique:

> *La sortie Q est active lorsque l’entrée A est active et lorsque l’entrée B est inactive.*

Pour réfléchir sur la logique, nous avons simplifié la phrase:

> *Je suis heureuse lorsqu'il fait soleil et lorsqu'il pleut.*

Nous avons donc la même structure:

> **Effet** lorsque **Événement 1** et lorsque **Événement 2**.

Mais nous interprétons de deux façons.

## Interprétation #1

Les deux événements doivent être concomitants pour que l'effet ait lieu. Cette interprétation se base sur le fait que les deux évènements sont liés dans la phrase par un `et lorsque` au lieu d'un `ou lorsque`. De plus, le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lorsque/47830) dit que *Lorsque* "*indique la concomitance dans le temps.*"

Ce faisant, je suis seulement heureuse s'il pleut pendant qu'il fait soleil. Donc, la sortie *Q* est seulement active lorsque l’entrée A est active pendant que l’entrée B est inactive.

L'expression logique est donc de `Q = A ET (NON B)`

## Interprétation #2

La répétition de `lorsque` indique que la phrase parle de deux cas différents non concomitants. L'effet n'a lieu que lorsque l'un des cas est vrai. D'ailleurs, le [HANSE](https://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_1995_num_67_1_3038_t1_0052_0000_3) précise que **lorsque** a le même sens que dans **dans le cas où**. La phrase simplifiée pourrait donc être réécrite comme :

> *Au moment où il fait soleil, je suis heureuse.*

ET

> *Au moment où il pleut, je suis heureuse.*

Dans ce cas, la sortie *Q* est active soit dans le cas où l’entrée A est active, soit dans le cas où l'entrée B est inactive.

L'expression logique est donc `Q = A OU (NON B)`

## Question

À quelle interprétation me fier ? Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Vu que c'est une question très sémantique, je pense pouvoir la poser ici.

Comment: En pure logique mathématique, j'aurais écrit ***si*** et non *lorsque*. Q = A ET (NON B) traduit fidèlement ce SI.

Comment: Sauf à vouloir piéger, quitte à utiliser *lorsque*, si j'avais voulu que l'on comprenne Q = A OU (NON B), j'aurais écrit "*...et **aussi** lorsque...*"

Comment: @aCOSwt - Mériterait d'être en réponse pour plussoiement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je pense que la bonne interprétation est l'interprétation 2.

Déjà du point de vue de l'expérience, j'ai travaillé sur ce genre d’énoncé dans mon université et l’interprétation retenue était la seconde.

Ensuite, du point de vue sémantique, le fait d'écrire deux fois *lorsque* revient à décrire deux moments différents. On peut observer ceci facilement avec l'exemple suivant : "Je me suis fait mal lorsque je me suis coupé et lorsque je me suis mordu". On voit bien que les deux actions (coupé/mordu) se sont passées à des moments distincts car il y a plusieurs *lorsque*. On peut donc étendre ce raisonnement à la logique : il y a autant de lorsque que de moments.

Donc proposition 2 : Q = A OU _B

Answer (score 0):

selon la notation du calcul propositionnel le problème s'analyse comme suit.

Q est active lorsque A  est active revient à si A alors Q ou en symboles: A→Q

Q est active lorsque B  est inactive revient à si non B alors Q ou en symboles: nonB→Q

On a donc ((A→Q) et ((nonB→Q)), ce qui s'écrit aussi selon un théorème d'équivalence :

(A ou nonB)→Q

Comment: Ce qui revient à dire " _S'il pleut, je suis heureuse et s'il fait soleil, je suis heureuse_", ce qui m'apparaît plus sensé que de dire "Je suis heureuse lorsqu'il pleut et fait soleil"

Comment: @D. Selon la réalité prépondérante  du temps météorologique, oui; cependant il peut pleuvoir en même temps que le soleil brille dans une partie dégagée du ciel et alors la dernière phrase correspond bien à quelque chose de réel; évidemment, « il pleut » ne peut plus alors être la négation logique de « il fait soleil ».

Comment: Mais si _Je suis heureuse lorsque je conçois des chaises et lorsque je change les roues de ma voiture._, ces deux évènements ne peuvent être concomitants, sauf si je suis forte à changer les roues d'une voiture tout en concevant des chaises.

Comment: @D. Disons que ce cas est associé à un plus grand degré de rareté. Je pense maintenant à ceci; il est possible de transformer la phrase et dire « Je suis heureuse soit qu'il fasse soleil, soit qu'il pleuve.» et alors on a une assertion dont tout soupçon d'ambigüité a disparu. On  introduit ainsi la notion du « ou exclusif ».